# Looking to use ffmpeg in shell to grab metadata

Tags: python, perl, shell, ffmpeg

I have a script that uses ffmpeg to convert mp3 to avi. I need to know how to grab the metadata from the mp3 using ffmpeg or the next best commang, ex. the metadata is:

```
    Input #1, mp3, from '21 - STACY BARTH - DRINK MY PAIN AWAY.mp3':
     Metadata:
artist          : DJ WHITEOWL
album           : Dj Whiteowl - R&b's New Generation
title           : STACY BARTH - DRINK MY PAIN AWAY
track           : 21/21
genre           : R&B
date            : 2012
TCMP            : 1
TDTG            : 2012-10-27T00:36:48
Duration: 00:05:02.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 191 kb/s
Stream #1.0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 192 kb/s
```

I need to grab the artist, album, title, track, genre, data etc and load them into separate variables. 
i.e

```
    track = 21/21
    genre = R&B
```

etc

Comment: Convert mp3 to avi? I don't understand what you're trying to do. avi is a container format that can contain mp3 audio.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
ffmpeg -i yourvide.mp4 -f ffmetadata
```

On OGG/MP3/M4A files the same command will work:

```
ffmpeg -i Guess_Im_Doing_Fine.mp3 -f ffmetadata
```

and it outputs all of the data you are interested in.  FFMPEG is a powerful tool and you should read the [docs](http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html).

output:

```
Input #0, mp3, from '03 Guess I'm Doing Fine.mp3':
Metadata:
title           : Guess I'm Doing Fine
artist          : Beck
album           : Sea Change
track           : 3
date            : 2002
genre           : Rock
Duration: 00:04:49.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 191 kb/s
Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 192 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It doesn't really output much useful AFAICT.

Comment: It outupts the metadata, i.e. title, artist, album, track, date, genre, duration.

Comment: How would I extract the data seperately, i.e only the title, and / or only the artist?

Comment: You can write the output to a file and parse the file or you could write a script, say python, that executes the command line argument I suggested and would assign the output of that argument to a variable as a string that you would parse for what you want.